# Link does not become "unvisited" again after refreshing the page. Why is that?

Tags: css, visited

I used the `a:visited` pseudo-class in CSS. The problem is when I refresh the page, the links still stays red, so they do not become "unvisited", that is to say blue again. Is that normal? Can I do something about it?

Comment: You could try clearing the browser history.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long will a browser remember a "a:visited" link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751805/how-long-will-a-browser-remember-a-avisited-link)

Comment: if link visit is stored in history it'll be visited as long as it's in your browsers histoy

Comment: in most cases it makes sense to only check for active not visited

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I don't really see how this question is going to benefit from an MCVE.

Comment: try to refresh using ctr+shift+R

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Welcome!

The `:visited` pseudo class marks every link that has been visited in the browsing history of the user. That means, that even after you reload the page the link stays "visited". An example is the google search, where visited links are purple. They only change back when clearing the browsing history.

This might not help you, since you didn't give any details regarding your environment but you could try to use the `:active` or `:focus` pseudo classes.